# Create a blazor component that accepts decimal and decimal? and returns string

Tags: blazor, .net-8.0

I'm trying to create a blazor component that accepts decimal or decimal? as bind-Value and returns a currency formatted string. It easy to make this work one input type but I'm not able to get it to work for both.

I've set Value as a decimal? parameter and setup the EventCallback for it. I display Value as a currency formatted string. If the string is set by the user I parse it as decimal and set Value. Again this all works find until trying to use the component with a non-nullable decimal. I get the follow error.

cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback'

```
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms;


<InputText @bind-Value="ValueText" style="@style" class="@Class"></InputText>

@code {    
    [Parameter]
    public decimal? Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<decimal?> ValueChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string? style { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string? Class { get; set; }
    
    private string? ValueText
    {
        get => $"{Value:c}";
        set
        {
            if (decimal.TryParse(value?.Replace("$", "").Replace(",", ""), out decimal output))
            {
                Value = output;
                ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried using @typeparam TItem, this looks like it comes close to working except I'm not able convert from the string value and then set Value.

```
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms;

@typeparam TItem;

<InputText @bind-Value="ValueText" style="@style" class="@Class"></InputText>

@code {    
    [Parameter]
    public TItem Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<TItem> ValueChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string? style { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string? Class { get; set; }
    
    private string? ValueText
    {
        get => $"{Value:c}";
        set
        {
            if (decimal.TryParse(value?.Replace("$", "").Replace(",", ""), out decimal output))
            {
                Value = output;
                ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);
            }
        }
    }
}`

Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'TItem'
```

Comment: Why do you have Value is nullable?  It doesn't make sense to pass to the component a Value that is null.  Try getting rid of the "?" and then assign a default value to Value such as zero.  I never use Parameters that are null I always assign them a default value.  So even Class I would initialize to string.Empty.